# Using Google Map API on Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, qualtrics

I am writing a survey on Qualtrics and want to display a Google Map, so a user can mark a location. I want to get the latitude and longitude from the marker. The problem I have is I get the longitude, but it will show up in the latitude text box. Also the latitude does not show up at all.I included a screenshot showing the problem. Here is my code. How do I get both the latitude and longitude to show up in the right text boxes?

```
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
    {
    /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/

    var google_maps_loaded = false; // no longer seems to be needed, nevertheless
    // no 'var' with functions
    loadedGoogleMapsAPI = function(){ google_maps_loaded = true; };
    // callback kinda required with google maps
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=REMOVED"
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    var canvas;
    var map;
    var marker;
    var question = this;
    var latitudeIndex  = question.getChoicesFromVariableName('Latitude').first() - 1;
    var longitudeIndex = question.getChoicesFromVariableName('Longitude').first() - 1;
    var lat = $(question.getChoiceContainer()).down('.InputText', latitudeIndex);
    var lng = $(question.getChoiceContainer()).down('.InputText', longitudeIndex);


    setMarkerLatLng = function(){
    if( lat.value && lng.value ){
        marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng(lat.value, lng.value)  );
};
};

     saveMarkerLatLng = function(){
     lat.value = marker.getPosition().lat();
     lng.value = marker.getPosition().lng();
     };

    showGoogleMap = function(){
    background = document.createElement("div");
    background.id = 'map_canvas_background';
    background.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: gray; opacity: 0.6;filter:alpha(opacity=60); top: 0px;');
document.body.appendChild(background);

wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.id = 'map_canvas_wrapper';
wrapper.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: auto; text-align: center; top: 0px;');
document.body.appendChild(wrapper);

canvas = document.createElement("div");
canvas.id = 'map_canvas';
canvas.setAttribute('style', 'width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 10px auto;');
wrapper.appendChild(canvas);

button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "This is the spot. Close GeoCoder.";
button.onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('map_canvas_background').remove();
  document.getElementById('map_canvas_wrapper').remove();
};
wrapper.appendChild(button);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.613567,-90.53524),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, mapOptions);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  draggable: true
});
setMarkerLatLng();
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseup", function(){saveMarkerLatLng();});
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event){
  marker.setPosition( event.latLng );
  saveMarkerLatLng();
});

}

});
```

[Sreenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUOji.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the setMarkerLatLng function you're checking the lat value twice instead of lat and lon.

Similarly in the saveMarkerLatLng function you are setting the lat value twice.

Comment: I changed the code to check lat and lng for both setMarkerLatLng and saveMargerLatLng. I am still having the same problem. I also updated the question with the updated code.

Comment: At what point is this not working? When the map loads? When you drag the marker? When you click on the map?

Comment: It does not work when I click to add the marker or when I drag the marker. It updates the longitude number. I checked and it is the right longitude for the area.

Comment: I've simulated your code and everything to do with google maps is working fine. It must be when you are setting the 2 indexes and `lat` and `lng` variables. Can you check those are selecting the correct fields?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:
`if( lat.value && lat.value )`

to this: `if( lat.value && lng.value ) //note lng not lat here`

as well as change this:

```
 saveMarkerLatLng = function(){
     lat.value = marker.getPosition().lat();
     lat.value = marker.getPosition().lng();
 };
```

to this:

```
 saveMarkerLatLng = function(){
     lat.value = marker.getPosition().lat();
     lng.value = marker.getPosition().lng(); // note lng not lat here
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by specifying the index of the latitude and longitude fields:

Instead of:

```
var lat = $(question.getChoiceContainer()).down('.InputText', latitudeIndex);
var lng = $(question.getChoiceContainer()).down('.InputText', longitudeIndex);
```

Use:

```
var lat = $(question.getChoiceContainer()).down('.InputText', 0);
var lng = $(question.getChoiceContainer()).down('.InputText', 1);
```

changing the 0 and 1 to the index of your fields.